# Difference between CDO.Message and System.Net.Mail

Tags: email, vbscript, system.net.mail, cdo.message

I've implemented email blasting system with C#.net application using System.Net.Mail.
Previously, this system was implemented with VB Script using CDO.Message.
After I deployed my new system and run it for blasting(sending emails), I got the exception(Error in processing Number of messages exceeds maximum per connection) in production SMTP Server. 
I know that this error is because of the SMTP server setting, but my client argues that the previous VB script can work with this SMTP Server setting.
That's why I want to know the difference between CDO.Message and System.Net.Mail, for instance, is there control of connection sessions, etc.
Please kindly advise me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

'CDO' is a COM implementation for sending mail whereas 'System.Net.Mail' is a managed way to send mail using SMTP (which is typically a relay to another mail server). You are likely to find limitations in sending a larger number of concurrent emails with both as a server can only handle so many. Concurrent requests - similar to a highway only being able to handle a finite number of cars at any one time.